# Embed Youtube video in iOS6 app opens video in Safari

Tags: youtube, embed, youtube-api, ios6

With iOS6 the old embed code no longer works, it just opens the video in Safari

I tried to use the new embed code, but when I make this dynamic it opens the video in Safari.

When I add a static entry in the webview it works, but it's rather slow and a lot of dom elements are injected

An example for the new embed code;

```
<iframe type="text/html" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID" frameborder="0"> </iframe>
```

I was thinking to use the HTML5 video tag and find out the url for the video, but this probably violates the Youtube TOS

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to set OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView to YES in Phonegap settings